# Paperclip doesn't store in a proper format fetched image by url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

When I trying to fetch a facebook image by the graph URL(https://graph.facebook.com), paperclip  stores avatar_image_name as "picture" in the database. The example of code:

```
img =  UserImages.new
img.avatar = URI.parse('https://graph.facebook.com/666980153384194/picture?type=large')
img.save
```

The  MySQL query in a console log:

```
=> #<URI::HTTPS:0x00000009954490 URL:https://graph.facebook.com/666980153384194/picture?type=large>
irb(main):009:0> img.save
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO `user_images` (`avatar_content_type`, `avatar_file_name`, `avatar_file_size`, `avatar_updated
_at`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('image/jpeg', 'picture', 6157, '2014-07-08 13:55:53', '2014-07-08 13:56:02', '
2014-07-08 13:56:02')
   (29.1ms)  COMMIT
```

As you can see fetched image file stored by the name 'picture'. But if to fetch image by Direct URL like:

```
https://scontent-a-lax.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/v/t1.0-9/10478546_662150043867205_2640371404472615909_n.jpg?oh=cb2fe9d421fef3d7d2220bb48a2a36e2&oe=5418E8FB
```

The fetched image stored as:

```
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Windows/AppData/Local/Temp/f1620d075c0642a77f7b98e532d8a8eb20140708-1040-1h5z4e6.jpg
"
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `user_images` (`avatar_content_type`, `avatar_file_name`, `avatar_file_size`, `avatar_updated
_at`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('image/jpeg', '10478546_662150043867205_2640371404472615909_n.jpg', 25862, '20
14-07-08 14:02:45', '2014-07-08 14:02:49', '2014-07-08 14:02:49')
   (34.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Any advise(solution) will be highly appreciated.

The source of  UserImages class:

```
  class UserImages < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable ,polymorphic: true
    has_attached_file :avatar,
                      :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "125x125>" },
                      :path => ":rails_root/public/images/users/:id/:style/:hash.:extension",
                      :default_url => "/images/normal/missing.jpg",
                      :url => "/images/users/:id/:style/:hash.:extension",
                      :hash_secret => "EWRWerrew234UTY"

    validates_attachment :avatar, :content_type =>  { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
                                      :size => { :in => 0..5.megabytes }

  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in both fetching URLs.... Both working fine...
The difference is only because paperclip generates the file name from the last part of the URL...
So in the first URL

https://graph.facebook.com/666980153384194/**picture**?type=large

And in the second URL

https://scontent-a-lax.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/v/t1.0-9/**10478546_662150043867205_2640371404472615909_n.jpg**?oh=cb2fe9d421fef3d7d2220bb48a2a36e2&oe=5418E8FB

I've bolded the part of the URL that paperclip is using to generate filename.... And in both cases you shouldn't really bother yourself with the file name... Since you can do any operation you want thought paperclip.

And you can make sure that the files are uploaded by checking the path `public/images/users/:id` (the paperclip path configuration)

Comment: Yes, Image is stored by the specified path. The name file has a hash format, but without a file extension: d8146a48c0f4fc3d916e57257c6270e91205ccbc 
It made a bit confused about how image is resolved :P

Comment: Yeah if paperclip couldn't figure the extension that will happen... If the file exists in that path and you could open it. Then it'll work on paperclip.